# How to break a foreach within a foreach correctly?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, break

So this is my current code:

```
foreach ($userItemsLoad as $item) {

    foreach ($dbItemsLoad as $items => $value) {

        if(array_key_exists($item['defindex'], $dbItemsLoad)) {
            echo $item['defindex'] . "</br>";
            echo $value['name'] . "</br>";
            break;
         }

    }            

}
```

`$item['defindex']` from `$userItemsLoad` is a string. This string is the key for a value in the `$dbItemsLoad` array.

If `$item['defindex']` matches the key of `$dbItemsLoad` I want to get the data of that key from `$dbItemsLoad`.

How do I achieve this?

When I'm using the above code, if I put the `break;` inside the second foreach the first loop keeps starting from the start which fails the purpose if i put it inside the first loop `$value['name']` is always the first value in that array.

`$userItemsLoad` looks like this:

```
 Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 669059101
        [original_id] => 669059101
        [defindex] => 15058
        [level] => 1
        [quality] => 4
        [inventory] => 2147483711
        [quantity] => 1
        [flag_cannot_trade] => 1
        [flag_cannot_craft] => 1
        [attributes] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [defindex] => 9
                        [value] => 3
                        [float_value] => 0
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [defindex] => 153
                        [value] => 1065353216
                        [float_value] => 1
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [defindex] => 14
                        [value] => 14
                        [float_value] => 0
                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 692723781
        [original_id] => 692723781
        [defindex] => 5039
        [level] => 1
        [quality] => 4
        [inventory] => 2147483673
        [quantity] => 1
        [flag_cannot_trade] => 1
        [flag_cannot_craft] => 1
```

`$dbItemsLoad` looks like this:

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Anti-Mage's Glaive
        [prefab] => default_item
        [image_inventory] => econ/heroes/antimage/antimage_weapon
        [item_description] => #DOTA_Item_Desc_AntiMages_Glaives
        [item_name] => #DOTA_Item_AntiMages_Glaive
        [item_type_name] => #DOTA_WearableType_Glaive
        [model_player] => models/heroes/antimage/antimage_weapon.vmdl
        [portraits] => Array
            (
```

defindex from array 1 equals to the key of array 2. i want the info from that key in array 2 such as name, image etc.

Comment: actually `break 2;` if you want to break

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested foreach loop, break inside loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341395/nested-foreach-loop-break-inside-loop)

Comment: break2, doesnot work. because it makes the loop only iterate onetime, i want to check id for 1 item which is in 1 array, this id from array 1 is the key of array in array 2.. so i if the id from array 1 matches the id of array 2 i want to get the data of that key from array 2.

Comment: @Aman `print_r(array_intersect_key(array_flip($array1), $array2));`

Comment: @Rizier123 array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values!

Comment: your if statement will evaluate to the same thing for all elements in the array

Comment: @Aman Change out: `array_flip($array1)` with `array_flip(array_column($array1, "defindex"))`

Comment: @Rizier123  i got values like this  [10222] => 27 now.

Comment: @Rizier123 could i add you on some im or something? if your willing to help that would be a little faster i believe.

Comment: @Aman [edit] your question; Make a little example: Give us 2 example arrays, what you currently get as output from your code + what you expect to get.

Comment: @Aman A **little** example: [MCVE]

Comment: @Aman Non of your `defindex` values is a key in the second array. Are you sure `print_r(array_intersect_key(array_flip(array_column($userItemsLoad, "defindex")), $dbItemsLoad));` doesn't give you what you want?

Comment: @Rizier123 in the particular code yes its not, but these arrays are really big, array 2 contains information for every cosmetic item in the dota 2 game on steam, array 1 is fetched using the steam api. So if i want to display which items the user has.. i need to compare the defindex in array 1 to key of array 2 for eg [1] in my array 2 would be the key.

Comment: your code gives me this output http://puu.sh/kQjdD/874028c77c.png, wut i need is: 
(
    [15058] => (Array
    (
        [name] => Anti-Mage's Glaive
        [prefab] => default_item
        [image_inventory] => econ/heroes/antimage/antimage_weapon )

Comment: @Aman Wups, change the order of arguments: `print_r(array_intersect_key($dbItemsLoad, array_flip(array_column($userItemsLoad, "defindex"))));`

Comment: @Rizier123 I dont know how you did it, but you did! i owe you, thank you so much, do you have a IM, i can add you on.. i wont bother you or anything would just like to have someone i can ask something if i hit a wall.

Comment: @Aman You're welcome. Just ask here on SO (Also see: [ask]).